# Test for one long word greater than window-width

Tags: emacs, elisp

The screenshot below was generated using `visual-line-mode`.  I am seeking to test whether a particular line could not be wrapped at word-end because the entire word exceeded the width of a window.

For example:  if the cursor is anywhere on line number 1, I would like to return `t` if `point-at-bol` to `point-at-eol` is *both* one long word that cannot be broken and it exceeds the `window-width`.

The same test should return `nil` if the cursor is anywhere on line 3.

I tried placing the cursor immediately before and immediately after the `\` symbol in the right-hand margin and attempting to identify that character with `what-cursor-position` but that particular symbol is not reachable with that function.  In other words, `\` doesn't seem to occupy a `(point)` in the usual sense of testing a point at window edge.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/example_05_06_2014_a.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function tests if the last word on the line is longer than the window width.

```
(defun too-long-p ()
  "Returns t if last word on the line is longer than the window's
column width."
  (save-excursion
    (end-of-line)
    (> (length (thing-at-point 'word))
       (window-total-width))))
```

And here's a version that addresses the "*both*" issue you raised, but I suspect the former may be closer to what you want.

```
(defun too-long-p ()
  "Returns t if last word on the line is longer than the window's
column width."
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (forward-word)
    (and (eolp)
         (> (length (thing-at-point 'word))
            (window-total-width)))))
```

In response to the comments, try this one (although I can't recall if tabs break lines, so you may need to edit the regexp):

```
(defun too-long-p ()
  "Returns t if last word on the line is longer than the window's
column width."
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (unless (re-search-forward "[ \t]"
                               (+ (point-at-bol) (window-total-width)) t)
      (> (length (thing-at-point 'line)) (window-total-width)))))
```

Comment: In this particular case, `;;;` is coming up as `nil` for `(thing-at-point 'word)` and also `nil` for `(thing-at-point 'symbol)`.  In text mode, `;` is considered to be a punctuation syntax constituent.  This answer does give me a few ideas, but does not appear to work for `;;;`.  I will read through the documentation to see how to define a particular thing:  *See the file 'thingatpt.el' for documentation on how to define a symbol as a valid THING.*

Comment: Something like that third example looks very promising, I'll give that a whirl in the next few hours and report back.  Thank you for the three (3) ideas.

Comment: D'oh!  Needed a `not` and an edge case for the last line in the buffer.  Revised the 3rd version to do that.